# Problems with Gitlab CI/CD on local machine

Tags: gitlab, cicd, gitlab-runner

I'm using `gitlab-runner` to run CI/CD locally.

It works properly when I specify all jobs in `.gitlab-ci.yml` like

```
stages:
  - test

test1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "ok"
```

and run `gitlab-runner exec shell test1`

In general, I'd like to store different jobs in different files. For example, I make `test-pipeline.yml` with jobs that relates to the `test` stage in the folder named `.gitlab`.

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` contains only to rows

```
include:
  local: .gitlab/test-pipeline.yml
```

I commit and push changes to the remote repo and it works there but the command `gitlab-runner exec shell job_name` fails because it can't find such job.

Perhaps, I have to edit some of gitlab-runner's config but it's not obviously.

Has anybody faced with the same problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[`gitlab-runner exec`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec) has [many limitations](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2797). It does not have all the same features of the regular gitlab-runner. One such limitation is that it [does not support the `include:` statement](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4378#note_202262291).

So, you won't be able to use `gitlab-runner exec` against this kind of config file that uses `include:`.